# Is there a program that can sync my documents, desktop, mail, and contacts between 2 macs

Tags: macos, sync

I have a Powermac G5 running 10.5 and a Macbook pro running 10.6.  What i'd like to do is have a program or setup where I can run something to syncronize all of my emails, contacts, and files between the 2.  I use the Powermac as my main computer but would like to press a button to have everything update on my MacBook Pro to go on a trip.  Then if i make modifications and put emails into folders, when I get back sync again to reflect those changes in my Powermac.  Is this a pipe dream or something like this exist.

The closest i've found is Chronosync:
http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_tips5.html

But doesn't seem to do mail and contacts.  Thanks!

Comment: ask on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com)?

Comment: Dropbox is amazing for files. Would Dropbox work with things like Mail and iCal, which are stored in Library? You could move the Mail folder, but what about calendars and contacts?

Comment: You can on windows via symlinks, which I believe OS X supports, but you'd have to find somebody more knowledgable about how OS X works. It's definately plausable, though.

Answer (score 0):

[rsync](http://www.google.com/#q=rsync+mac+os+x) is the clasic answer. Here is a tutorial: http://www.bombich.com/mactips/rsync.html

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html) is a need new way of doing things

Both of these solutions assume that Mac is like UNIX is that all configs are stored in data files that can be synced between two machines (i.e., not in a registry hidden off somewhere)